opsForStream.pending command is not working with Range other than unbounded
Is it possible to provide some of ID's in range, instead of Range.unbounded() option?
I didn't find any of examples and maybe there is an defect, because if String is provided in Range (lower or upper) I'm facing the issue:
class java.nio.HeapByteBuffer cannot be cast to class java.lang.String (java.nio.HeapByteBuffer and java.lang.String are in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')

It looks like the issue in org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.RangeConverter.convertBound method
Because when we provide String as value it uses StringCodec.UTF8::encodeValue default decoder and StringCodec.encodeValue method returns ByteBuffer object, instead of String.
Then in RedisCommandBuilder.getRange method we expect Boundary boundary but in fact we have Boundary boundary argument.
I want to use record id in opsForStream.pending with Range argument properly:
var messagesSummary = opsForStream.pending(streamConfigProperties.name(), streamConfigProperties.group()).block();

var pendingMono = opsForStream.pending(
    streamConfigProperties.name(), streamConfigProperties.group(),
    messagesSummary.getIdRange(), streamConfigProperties.reprocessBatch()
);

